# How to parse dictionary values based on conditions

Tags: python, dictionary

My dictionary looks like this:

```
{'0': 'correct g',
 '1': 'correct g',
 '2': 'incorrect ng',
 '3': 'correct g',
 '4': 'correct g',
 '5': 'incorrect g',
 '6': 'incorrect ng'}
```

I want to identify **consecutive** values after `incorrect ng` that equal `correct g` and return their corresponding keys.

So the output would look something like...

```
{2: [3,4]}
```

where 2 is the key for `incorrect ng` and the list of values are the **consecutive** keys that have values that equal `correct g`

To identify the `incorrect ng` I have:

```
{k:v for k,v in dictionary.items() if v == 'incorrect ng'}
```

But I don't know how I'd be able to continue down the values until I hit another `incorrect ng`.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered. You might want to consider a different data structure

Comment: That's why I chose to represent my data as numerical keys so they stay ordered

Comment: As @Hamms noted, what your asking doesn't make much sense because dictionaries are **un-ordered data structures**. There order changes randomly. The first time you accesses the dictionary there could be three `correct g`'s between two `incorrect g`'s and the next time none. Consider using `collections.OrderedDict` instead.

Comment: @e9e9s Using numerical keys doesn't change the fact that dictionaries are un-ordered data structures.

Comment: I think OP only cares about the `correct g`'s between two `incorrect g`'s that are in order numerically. And so, to access the data, OP would have to sort the keys, then access the dictionary entries in that order.

Comment: Yes, I sorted the keys before so they appeared like how they do in the example.  And yes I only care about the number of **consecutive** `correct g`'s after `incorrect ng`'s

Comment: @Antimony: yes, but then why use a dict? A list is more natural: if you find where the incorrect ones are ([2, 6]) then you implicitly know what the OP is asking for.

Comment: I see what you're saying but the dict can also have `correct ng` or `incorrect g` as values as well.  I simplified the example to make it easier to explain.

Comment: @e9e9s I think we should just answer the question :-)

Comment: @ChristianDean: the order may be arbitrary, but doesn't change randomly. The order is stable until you add or delete keys.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I know. I meant the order randomly changes _when_ you add or delete keys. I agree I should've been more specific.

Comment: @e9e9s Once you have found an answer which works for you, please click the tick next to that answer to accept it. This lets other people with your problem know which solution works for you.

Comment: @e9e9s I have added a solution, based on what I read in the comments and the question. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
newDict = {}
Arr = []
num = -1
start = False

for key in dictionary:

    value = dictionary[key]

    if value == 'incorrect ng' and start == False:
        num = int(key)
        start = True
    elif value == 'incorrect ng' and start == True:
        start = False 
    elif value == 'correct g' and start == True:
        Arr.append(key)

if num != -1:
    newDict[int(num)] = Arr
    print(newDict)
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that every item has a numerical key, and that there are no gaps, you could just iterate through the items like so:

```
answer = {}

for key in range(len(dictionary)):
    if dictionary[key] == 'incorrect ng':
        answer[key] = []
        for next_key in range(key, len(dictionary)):
            if dictionary[next_key] == 'correct g':
                answer[key].append(next_key)
            else:
                break
```

When you get the first `'incorrect ng'`, just keep track of its key value, then look at the next few entries until you hit an entry that is not `'correct g'`.

Answer (score -1):

Please note that by default dictionary in python 2.7 does not preserve order. So use `OrderedDict` to preserve order or simply use a `list`

```
from collections import OrderedDict, defaultdict

values = OrderedDict()
values['0'] = 'correct g'
values['1'] = 'correct g'
values['2'] = 'incorrect ng'
values['3'] = 'correct g'
values['4'] = 'correct g'
values['5'] = 'incorrect g'
values['6'] = 'incorrect ng'

results = defaultdict(list)
new_key = None
for key in values:
    # when we encounter 'incorrect ng' we will set it as new_key.
    if values[key] == 'incorrect ng':
        new_key = key
    elif values[key] == 'correct g' and new_key:
        # if new_key is present and current value is 'correct g'
        results[new_key].append(key)
    else:
        # any other key value comes in between then we clear the new_key
        # remove this piece of code if intermediate values could be 'correct ng' or other things.
        new_key = None

results
```

output:

```
defaultdict(list, {'2': ['3', '4']})
```